# STM32F0 SPI receive interrupt not firing

Tags: c, microcontroller, interrupt, stm32, spi

I have a simple project, created using CubeMX for the peripheral initialisation.

SPI is in slave mode, and appears to be initialised correctly, but when I clock 8 bits of data, the interrupt doesn't get called.

Here's the code

```
/* SPI1 init function */
static void MX_SPI1_Init(void)
{

  hspi1.Instance = SPI1;
  hspi1.Init.Mode = SPI_MODE_SLAVE;
  hspi1.Init.Direction = SPI_DIRECTION_2LINES;
  hspi1.Init.DataSize = SPI_DATASIZE_8BIT;
  hspi1.Init.CLKPolarity = SPI_POLARITY_LOW;
  hspi1.Init.CLKPhase = SPI_PHASE_1EDGE;
  hspi1.Init.NSS = SPI_NSS_SOFT;
  hspi1.Init.FirstBit = SPI_FIRSTBIT_MSB;
  hspi1.Init.TIMode = SPI_TIMODE_DISABLE;
  hspi1.Init.CRCCalculation = SPI_CRCCALCULATION_DISABLE;
  hspi1.Init.CRCPolynomial = 7;
  hspi1.Init.CRCLength = SPI_CRC_LENGTH_DATASIZE;
  hspi1.Init.NSSPMode = SPI_NSS_PULSE_DISABLE;

  if (HAL_SPI_Init(&hspi1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

}

void HAL_SPI_MspInit(SPI_HandleTypeDef* hspi)
{

  GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct;
  if(hspi->Instance==SPI1)
  {
  /* USER CODE BEGIN SPI1_MspInit 0 */

  /* USER CODE END SPI1_MspInit 0 */
    /* Peripheral clock enable */
    __HAL_RCC_SPI1_CLK_ENABLE();

    /**SPI1 GPIO Configuration    
    PA5     ------> SPI1_SCK
    PA6     ------> SPI1_MISO
    PA7     ------> SPI1_MOSI 
    */
    GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_5|GPIO_PIN_6|GPIO_PIN_7;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_AF_PP;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_HIGH;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Alternate = GPIO_AF0_SPI1;
    HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStruct);

    /* Peripheral interrupt init */
    HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(SPI1_IRQn, 0, 0);
    HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(SPI1_IRQn);
  /* USER CODE BEGIN SPI1_MspInit 1 */

  /* USER CODE END SPI1_MspInit 1 */
  }

}

void SPI1_IRQHandler(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN SPI1_IRQn 0 */

  /* USER CODE END SPI1_IRQn 0 */
  HAL_SPI_IRQHandler(&hspi1);
  /* USER CODE BEGIN SPI1_IRQn 1 */
  spi_interrupt();
  /* USER CODE END SPI1_IRQn 1 */
}
```

The `spi_interrupt()` is my specific code for the interrupt actions, and a breakpoint in there never fires.

I've got a scope on the CLKIN pin, and its definitely got the 8 clocks.

Comment: Did you called the `HAL_SPI_Receive_IT` anywhere in your code? Because to actually enable the interrupt you have to call this macro `__HAL_SPI_ENABLE_IT(hspi, (SPI_IT_RXNE | SPI_IT_ERR));` the  `HAL_SPI_Receive_IT` calls it for you and the IRQ handler disables it after the given number of bytes are received.

Comment: Thank you Bence, that was the correct solution :)

Comment: Glad to here it, I will put it in an answer then.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ST's HAL library won't enable the actual peripheral interrupts in the initialization function.

For almost all of the peripherals an additional function has to be called which always has the following name structure `HAL_<peripheral>_<action>_IT` so in case of SPI RX it is called `HAL_SPI_Receive_IT`.

This enables actually the SPI RX interrupt by setting the correct bit with a macro called: `__HAL_SPI_ENABLE_IT(hspi, (SPI_IT_RXNE | SPI_IT_ERR))`.

Note that if the number of expected bytes (this value is passed in the `HAL_SPI_Receive_IT` by the user) is reached then the `HAL_SPI_IRQHandler` will disable the SPI RX interrupt again, thus a repeated `HAL_SPI_Receive_IT` call is needed in case of a new reception.